# what is the covariance matrix for deterministic signal+normal noise

Tags: normal-distribution, noise

Say that we have a signal that is written as follow $y=y_0+r$ where $y$ and $y_0$ are n-dimensional vectors and $r$ is n-dimensional noise vector.
I would like to have $r\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma=\sigma^2I_{n,n}\in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$ is the covariance matrix of the vector $r$.
So my question is how can I generate $r$ such that $r\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I_{n,n})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I_{n,n}$ is the ientity matrix, start from $n$ independent standard normal random variables $x_k$ and define the random vector $r$ by $r=(\sigma x_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$.

Comment: I guess that you meant $r=(\sigma^2 x_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ right?

Then all that I need to do is to write $r=\sigma^2 x$ where $x$ is n-dimensional vector whose entries are independent normal random variables.

is that correct?

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote (and what you suggest does not yield the covariance matrix you are after).

Comment: @Did, what if $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary (i.e., a symmetric positive definite) covariance matrix?

Comment: @nullgeppetto Then one considers $r=Lx$ where $x=(x_k)$ and $LL^*=\Sigma$.